# Sed: individuate region and clean before and after

Tags: awk, sed

I have some pages, they all contain at a certain point`<article>` and after another certain point`</article>`

How can I use sed to delete every line before and every line after these tags?

I tried:

```
sed '/<article>/,/</article>/ !d'
```

but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sentence is just mising a `\` to espace the `/` character:

```
sed '/<article>/,/<\/article>/ !d'
```

Another way to accomplish the same:

```
sed '\#<article>#,\#</article># !d'
```

---

From [man sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
Adresses:

\cregexpc
    Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.  
    The c may be any character.
```